# extended mail merge

Tags: email

I would like to have Extended Mail Merge enabled for my Developer Edition of SF.  How can I accomplish this when I can not open up a case to SF, because they do not take cases from the 'free' developer edition.
Thanks.
Bruce

Comment: Call 1800nosoftware ( salesforce general line) and choose basic support and request them to enable exended mail merge by providing your username. It may/may not happen depending on their policies, but would be worth a try. I activated multi currency for my dev org by calling basic support.

Comment: Why, oh why, don't you answer the question properly...?

Comment: When rao gets around to it, I'll make sure he mentions that you *may not get it the first time around*. Call two or three times. When you get the right person, they'll usually enable it for you.

Comment: @rao Post a real answer so it can be upvoted and accepted!

Comment: sfdcfox I generally comment because I feel like having cheated the system and got some points than answering a real question when I make such statements. Also I hate downvotes, so I try to play safe. Will make it a point to post as answer than comment going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Call 1800nosoftware ( salesforce general line) and choose basic support and request them to enable exended mail merge by providing your username. It may/may not happen depending on their policies, but would be worth a try. I activated multi currency for my dev org by calling basic support.